# Ubuntu having a weird problem whille detecting for /

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, error-handling, tmp

This is happening rapidly and since 3 days. It has happened 3 times. 
when the boot splash screen appears, while booting, i see an error saying that `problems were detected while checking for /`
and after that it asks me to repair by pressing a key and after that it says that `problems were found while checking for /tmp` 
and after that it again reboots and works normally
please tell me that what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a lot of this question was solved on chat - I'll ask @Utkarsh to update his question somewhat. Apparently the system was giving errors to do with the hard drive.

The first step was to rule out hardware failure though the use of SMART - gsmartcontrol is a good frontend for it for a neophyte user, and there weren't any errors found through it.

The next step was to find and fix data corruption

```
sudo su
cd /
touch /forcefsck
reboot
```

As root, creating a /forcefsck and rebooting told the system to run a check before mounting the filesystem. I'm told that that fixed the issue